# Insert data when no match by update_by_query in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, update-by-query

I have this command that don't match any data in elastic search and I want to insert it after that.

```
//localhost:9200/my_index/my_topic/_update_by_query
{
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.NAME = params.NAME",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params": {
            "NAME": "kevin"
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "terms": {
            "_id": [
                999
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I try using `upsert` but it return errors `Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [upsert].`

I don't want using `update` + `doc_as_upsert` cause I have a case that I will don't send `id` in my `update` query.

How can I insert this with `update_by_query`. Thank you.

If elastic search don't support. I think I will check condition if have `id` or not, and use `indexAPI` to create and `update` to update.

Answer (score 0):

`_update_by_query` runs on **existing documents** contained in an **existing index**. What `_update_by_query` does is scroll over all documents in your index (that optionally match a query) and perform some logic on each of them via a script or an ingest pipeline.

Hence, logically, you cannot create/upsert data that doesn't already exist in the index. The Index API will always overwrite your document. Upsert only works with in conjunction with the `_update` endpoint, which is what you should probably do.

Comment: I read this [update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-update.html#_updates_with_a_partial_document) and ```id``` is mandatory. How can I insert when I don't want to pass ```id``` .

Comment: Can you better explain your use case so we can help you. It seems you're misunderstanding what update by id and update by query are doing. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I have data that will update when I pass id, and create new data if It don't have id. I just want to use only 1 API of elastic.